# Download server and automatically deploy war with Maven

Tags: java, git, maven, deployment, automation

I am a trainee in a large company, we have a maven project + git + spring that run. I developed Selenium test for the HMI.
Now I need to configure the pom.xml (I'm really new in this domain) for:

1. Compile normally the source into a jar (that it works)
2. Run the unit test (that it works)
3. Download (via maven) server (tomcat / jetty / ...) not installed locally
4. Deploy the war on the temporary server
5. Start the Selenium test on the war be deployed, (local host)
6. Get an overview of the tests performed

I can not seem to find an approach to automate the download and installation of the server (automatic and temporary), deploy the war and then run Selenium tests on deployed war.

Is someone will have a way to solve my problem?
I do not I realize if it's REALLY complicated or not.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) to do this. It can download the server from an URL and then start it, deploy your WAR/EAR. 
You need to setup your Maven `pom.xml` with some different executions and lifecycle stuff to get the server started/stopped etc but there are plenty examples on the Cargo [homepage](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Starting+and+stopping+a+container).

Comment: I'll see if I can dig up an example from my source code later today.

Comment: o! nice. I'm already studying Cargo, but I look forward to your example: D

Comment: I try to run with cargo since friday... I don't understand why fail. There are always a problem... And finally when eclipse say 'war deploy on http://...'  the link is a 404 page..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>C:/git/Repo/web/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <warFile>C:/git/Repo/web/src/main/webapp/repository-3.0.4-selenium-SNAPSHOT.war</warFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It will of course change the address of war, giving your path generation(`<warSourceDirectory>` && `<warFile>`).